# Call to undefined function in upgradelib.php while upgrading

Tags: moodle

I'm doing an update for a Moodle plugin. Basically all I want to do is to add some fields to an existing table in database.

Here's my `upgrade.php` built from the XMLDB editor:

```
function xmldb_qtype_myqtype_upgrade($oldversion = 0) {
global $DB;
$dbman = $DB->get_manager();

$result = true;

if ($oldversion < 2013031601) {

    // Define table solib to be created
    $table = new xmldb_table('solib');

    // Adding fields to table solib
    $table->add_field('id', XMLDB_TYPE_INTEGER, '10', null, XMLDB_NOTNULL, XMLDB_SEQUENCE, null);
    $table->add_field('course', XMLDB_TYPE_INTEGER, '10', null, XMLDB_NOTNULL, null, '0');
    $table->add_field('name', XMLDB_TYPE_CHAR, '255', null, XMLDB_NOTNULL, null, null);
    $table->add_field('timestamp', XMLDB_TYPE_INTEGER, '10', null, XMLDB_NOTNULL, null, null);
    $table->add_field('server_addr', XMLDB_TYPE_CHAR, '255', null, XMLDB_NOTNULL, null, null);
    $table->add_field('access_token', XMLDB_TYPE_INTEGER, '20', null, XMLDB_NOTNULL, null, null);

    // Adding keys to table solib
    $table->add_key('primary', XMLDB_KEY_PRIMARY, array('id'));

    // Conditionally launch create table for solib
    if (!$dbman->table_exists($table)) {
        $dbman->create_table($table);
    }

    // solib savepoint reached
    upgrade_mod_savepoint(true, 2013031601, 'solib');
}

return $result;
}
```

I also updated the install.xml file, even if I'm not sure it interferes with an upgrade, it's only for new users of the plugin.

Then I change the version number in `version.php` and I run the update, but I'm always facing this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function xmldb_solib_upgrade() in /var/www/moodle/lib/upgradelib.php on line 629
```

I assume this is not a Moodle bug and I'm missing something. But what? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

```
xmldb_qtype_myqtype_upgrade()
```

needed to be defined as:

```
xmldb_solib_upgrade() // plugin name as 'qtype_myqtype'
```

The main reason why I did not understand the error was because it was located in `/moodle/lib/upgradelib.php` and not in the dumped file: `/moodle/mod/solib/db/upgrade.php`. This precision isn't very clear in the documentation either.